# Is it possible to change library linking order in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

When I execute `make`, it executes something like `gcc blah.o -lXtst -lX11` and that causes an error like `undefined reference to XTestFakeButtonEvent`. I've discovered plenty answers and all of them says that it's because of wrong linking order. It's easy to change order when using plain `gcc`, but what about `make`?

Comment: Sure, change the order when you add the dependencies for your target. You did not share CMake code, so difficult to be more explicit. You do not change the linking order within make, but CMake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two answers here, a lazy one and a right one.

The lazy one is, the order in which you specify dependencies to `target_link_libraries` is the order in which they appear on the command line.

This however is not a very satisfactory answer, as keeping track of dependencies this way is rather tedious and very prone to maintenance errors.

A better solution is to model all dependencies explicitly. That is, model each dependency as its own target (possibly using [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) if dealing with precompiled dependencies) and then model inter-target dependencies correctly using `target_link_libraries` or [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_dependencies.html). If you do this throughout your project, you will (almost) never have to worry about the order, because CMake just takes care of it for you.

Comment: I just encountered this problem with cmake version 3.24. Turns out when using imported targets, the order is *not* maintained. In case of a common dependency, I have to use `target_link_libraries` on the imported_target rather than the final target: `target_link_libraries(imported_target INTERFACE dependency)` Only then -ldependency will be put after -limported_target in the call to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add *XTestFakeButtonEvent* as **target_link_libraries** to the library (module) **CMakeLists.txt** the undefined reference are happening with. then *cmake* will finally understand the dependency requirements.